# PN junction under forward or reverse bias, there is a current continuity through the depletion region

Tags: optics

Will there be some generations by thermal happened in the depletion region?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to know, it is not clear from the current text (and your question will likely be closed).

Comment: Yes, there will always be carrier generation occurring in the depletion region. Sometimes known as dark current, particularly for photodiodes.

Comment: Many thanks for answering my question. Sorry for not say it clearly. Actually I read from a book, it says under the forward bias, 'assumed that the current density of the electrons is the same at both edges of the depletion region, and I have assumed the same thing for the holes. The assumption implies current continuity through the depletion region with no generation or recombination in the depletion region itself.'

Comment: Above here is the original saying by the author, only omit the picture. So I wonder if this no generation in the depletion region only worked under this assumption? In this assumption, the current density is constant, does that mean the current density is not constant in reality?